# I dont know how to configure Prolog for VScode, can someone help me?

Tags: visual-studio-code, prolog, swi-prolog

I have opened a folder where I have some projects on Prolog, and I open that folder in the explorer from VScode, when i try to open a terminal an use the command swipl this error pops up:

> swipl : The term 'swipl' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file or executable program.
> Check if you typed the name correctly, or, if you included a path, check that the path is correct and
> try again.
> Inline: 1 Character: 1
> + swipl
> + ~~~~~
> + CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (swipl:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

I would like to know what I have to do to solve it.

I was trying to use Prolog in VScode, and I was expecting the command 'swipl' to work so I could work with Prolog.

Comment: is that a PowerShell error? where/what shell are you running the command in? How exactly did you install Prolog?

Comment: As instructed in [ask], can you please write a descriptive, non-ambiguous title? For more guidance, see [How do I write a good title?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/10647/997587)